# Low priority job in OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, visual-studio-2008, thread-priority

I am trying to call feature detectors from `OpenCV` in my C++ application written in Visual Studio. I would like to run this operation in the background and do not care about its timing. Actually, I prefer if it is not interfering with the main performance of the application. To this end, I perform the feature detection in a separate thread and tried to lower the priority of the thread with the command `SetThreadPriority()`. This is however not working, and while the `OpenCV` function is running, all the CPU cores are maxed out. Is there any way to control the priority of the tasks in `OpenCV` or even limit the CPU cores involved in its process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find any way to reduce the priority of an `OpenCV` job, I could reduce the CPU usage by using `setNumThreads(int numThreads)`.